# How many patterns can be built from sequences of these musical notes?

Tags: combinatorics

This is probably a simple question but hard for me to prove to myself I'm getting the right answer. Say you have $7$ musical notes in a scale, you can play 4 of them before the melody repeats. What are all the number of possible melodies you can create, *subtracting the ones that are simply shifted over by some number of beats*?

For example, call the notes 1 - 7, we have:

```
1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2
```

Then we have:

```
1 3 5 3 1 3 5 3 ...
```

They are different completely. But then we have:

```
2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 ...
```

Which is the same as the first it just started on a different beat.

Don't know how to phrase this precisely, but how would you calculate how many possibilities there are ($7^4$) *minus* the ones offset by a number of beats? It gets complex because you could have:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

And that is just one possibility, there is no rotation.

Then you have:

```
1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...
or
2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
```

Where there are only two options, but there is only one real "beat" given they are offset each other.

I'm not quite sure how to dig into further and solve this problem without manually enumerating the possibilities.

So I guess there are 3 cases:

```
1 1 1 1 ... 1 types
1 2 1 2 ... 2 types
1 2 3 3 1 2 3 3
2 3 3 1 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 2 3 3 1 2
3 1 2 3 3 1 2 3 ... 4 types
```

So somehow you have to do $7^4$ `- 7 (for type 1)` then `- x number of type 2 / 2` then `- y number of type 3 / ?`, I'm not quite sure. Any help would be appreciated. I would be curious to see how you figured it out.

I am going to use this to figure out for $5$, $7$, or $12$ note scales, for $3$-$11$ beats per repeat.

Comment: There's a typo at the end of the first melody.

Comment: These are [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @joriki thanks, corrected, ooh I have never heard of necklaces

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the general expression for the number of [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) of length $n$ over an alphabet of size $k$,

$$
\frac1n\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)k^{\frac nd}\;,
$$

with $n=4$ and $k=7$, we get

$$
\frac14\left(\varphi(1)7^4+\varphi(2)7^2+\varphi(4)7^1\right)=\frac14\left(1\cdot7^4+1\cdot7^2+2\cdot7^1\right)=\frac{2464}4=616\;,
$$

in agreement with Zoe Allen’s answer.

Comment: I gotta look up what `d` is, it's not obvious from the equation.

Comment: @Lance: $d\mid n$ means "$d$ divides $n$". The sum is over all divisors of $n$.

Answer (score 3):

There are only three possibilities: it can have period 1, 2, or 4. There are 7 period 1 sequences, and these only get counted once, so we don't need to account for double-counting. There are $7^2 - 7$ period 2 sequences, but this is double counting, so we need to only count half of this. There are $7^4-7^2$ period 4 sequences, and these are being quadruple counted, so we need to only count a quarter of this. So the number we get is

$$7 + \frac{7^2-7}{2} + \frac{7^4-7^2}{4} = 616$$

Comment: Amazing! Can you show a generalized solution for arbitrary number of beats (3-11 in my case), and arbitrary number of notes (1-12 notes)? I don't see what your 616 number is referencing, is it hardcoded to 4 beats I think?